# fatal error in php code

Tags: php

I am running a php program control.php which calls another program functions.php but there is an error
my programs are given below

**CONTROL.PHP**

```
$sleeptime = 125000;
require("functions.php");

$temp = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
if (is_numeric($temp)) {
    if ($temp >= 66 && $temp <= 88) {
        echo "Setting temperature to {$temp}F...\n";
        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
        reset_ac();
        $up = $temp - 66;
        updeg($up);
        echo "Done.\n";



    } else {
        echo "Temperature must be a number between 66 and 88!\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Temperature must be a number!\n";
}
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
//relay control board functions
$relay['ip'] = "192.168.10.180";
$relay['read'] = "public";
$relay['write'] = "private";
$relay['base'] = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.";
$relay['base'] = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.19865.1.2.";

$relay['num'][1] = "1.1.0";
$relay['num'][2] = "1.2.0";
$relay['num'][3] = "1.3.0";
$relay['num'][4] = "1.4.0";
$relay['num'][5] = "1.5.0";
$relay['num'][6] = "1.6.0";
$relay['num'][7] = "1.7.0";
$relay['num'][8] = "1.8.0";
$relay['num'][9] =  "2.1.0";
$relay['num'][10] = "2.2.0";
$relay['num'][11] = "2.3.0";
$relay['num'][12] = "2.4.0";
$relay['num'][13] = "2.5.0";
$relay['num'][14] = "2.6.0";
$relay['num'][15] = "2.7.0";
$relay['num'][16] = "2.8.0";
$relay['num'][17] = "3.1.0";
$relay['num'][18] = "3.2.0";
$relay['num'][19] = "3.3.0";
$relay['num'][20] = "3.4.0";
$relay['num'][21] = "3.5.0";
$relay['num'][22] = "3.6.0";
$relay['num'][23] = "3.7.0";
$relay['num'][24] = "3.8.0";

//returns the value of the specified relay
function getrelay($val) {
    global $relay;
    $data = snmpget($relay['ip'],$relay['read'],"{$relay['base']}{$relay['num'][$val]}");
    return $data;
}

//sets a specified relay on or off
function setrelay($val, $val2) {
    global $relay;
    $data = snmpset($relay['ip'],$relay['write'],"{$relay['base']}{$relay['num'][$val]}","i","$val2","0");
    return $data;
}

//resets all relays to off
function clear() {
    for ($a = 1; $a <= 16; $a++) {
        setrelay($a, 0);
    }
}

function reset_ac() {
    global $sleeptime;
    echo "Resetting to 66F";
    for ($a = 1; $a <= 22; $a++) {
        setrelay(1,1);
        echo ".";

        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
        setrelay(1,0);

        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
    }
    echo " Done.\n";
}

function updeg($deg) {
    global $sleeptime;
    echo "Stepping up {$deg}F";
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $deg; $a++) {
        setrelay(2,1);
        echo ".";

        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
        setrelay(2,0);

        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
    }
    echo " Done.\n";
}

function downdeg($deg) {
    global $sleeptime;
    echo "Stepping up {$deg}F";
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $deg; $a++) {
        setrelay(1,1);
        echo ".";

        flush();
        usleep($sleeptime);
        setrelay(1,0);

        flush();        
        usleep($sleeptime);
    }
    echo " Done.\n";
}
```

The error is showing as **Fatal Error : Unable to define snmpset() in /root/functions.php on line 44**

Please help

Comment: That's not the whole error message. It tells you in which line number it occurs, and also where the function was previously declared. If both are identical, then you are just including a script twice.

Comment: Have you checked whether SNMP support is enabled in your installation?

Comment: i am doing it in linux... do i need to install snmp support?? if yes then how?

Comment: Try changing `"{$relay['base']}{$relay['num'][$val]}"` to `$relay['base'].$relay['num'][$val]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SNMP support compiled into your PHP? See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.setup.php